# page redirection in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

what I have: 
a google search form (displayed on all pages)
a wordpress page to display search results

what I want to do:
when a search is performed, redirect to the page containing the search results

how do I do this?

the search results page is a wordpress-created page with a permalink domain.com/search-results

Comment: why don't you use the wordpress native search or a google search plugin? http://google.com/search?q=wordpress+google+search+plugin what are you doing is some kinda weired!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your template files doesn't have a file called "search.php" then create one, 
this is were all the results will be shown, do a standard wp loop and style it..
thats if you were using the standard wp search, in this case

apply a template tag to the top of a new php page,

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Search_Results
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
or include a new one
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/header_search.php'); ?>

<!-- INCLUDE GOOGLE SCRIPT -->

<?php get_sidebar();?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

this should print out your results...